# Some particles appear too bright

Tags: modeling, particles

So I was watching Blender Guru's videos on donut making in Blender and when it came to the sprinkles they showed up super bright on the rendering. I don't know what happened. In the image, you can see the spherical sprinkles are just fine but the rest aren't  [image: In the image you can see the spherical sprinkles are just fine but the rest aren't.]

Comment: share blender file please

Comment: have you tried changing the material?

Comment: It looks like you used an Emission shader or changed the Emission color of the Principal BSDF shader.

Comment: @sanbaldo *If* you're asking someone to upload a blend file and *if* it is needed then it's better to suggest *where* users should upload to, i.e. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I don't know what i did that made them look like that but i restarted and everything is fine Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your particles are actually emitting light. In order for this to happen, they either have an emission shader, or a principled shader in which the Emission value is not set to black.

If the particles using an emission shader, simply change it to a principled shader and that should fix the problem. If they are using a principled shader, simply go to the Emission box and set it to black.
[image: A screenshot of the blender principled shader interface, emphasizing the black color box next to the "Emission" property]

Comment: it can also be some "bloom" effect in Evee